# Can I use Apache mod_proxy as a connection pool, under the Prefork MPM?

Tags: apache, connection-pooling, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

**Summary/Quesiton:**

I have Apache running with Prefork MPM, running php. I'm trying to use Apache mod_proxy to create a reverse proxy that I can re-route my requests through, so that I can use Apache to do connection pooling. Example impl:

in httpd.conf:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /test_proxy/ https://destination.server.com/ min=1 keepalive=On ttl=120
```

but when I run my test, which is the following command in a loop:

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:80/test_proxy/testpage'
```

it doesn't seem to re-use the connections.

After some further reading, it sounds like I'm not getting connection pool functionality because I'm using the Prefork MPM rather than the Worker MPM. So each time I make a request to the proxy, it spins up a new process with its own connection pool (of size one), instead of using the single worker that maintains its own pool. Is that interpretation right?

---

**Background info:**

There's an external server that I make requests to, over https, for every page hit on a site that I run.

Negotiating the SSL handshake is getting costly, because I use php and it doesn't seem to support connection pooling - if I get 300 page requests to my site, they have to do 300 SSL handshakes to the external server, because the connections get closed after each script finishes running.

So I'm attempting to use a reverse proxy under Apache to function as a connection pool, to persist the connections across php processes so I don't have to do the SSL handshake as often.

Sources that gave me this idea:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html
- http://geeksnotes.livejournal.com/21264.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your test method cannot demonstrate connection pooling since for every call, a curl client is born and then it dies. Like dead people don't talk a lot, a dead process cannot keep a connection alive.

You have clients that bothers your proxy server.

```
Client ====== (A) =====> ProxyServer
```

Let's call this connection A. Your proxy server does nothing, it is just a show off. The handsome and hardworking server is so humble that he hides behind.

```
Client ====== (A) =====> ProxyServer ====== (B) =====> WebServer
```

Here, if I am not wrong, the secured connection is A, not B, right?

Repeating my first point, on your test, you are creating a separate client for each request. Every client needs a separate connection. Connection is something that happens between at least two parties. One side leaves and connection is lost.

Okay, let's forget curl now and look together at what we really want to do.

We want to have SSL on A and we want A side of traffic to be as fast as possible. For this aim, we have already separated side B so it will not make A even slower, right?

Connection pooling? There is no such thing as connection pooling at A. Every client comes and goes making a lot of noise. Only thing that can help you to reduce this noise is "Keep-Alive" which means, keeping connection alive from **a** client for some short period of time so this very same client can ask for other files that will be required by this request. When we are done, we are done.

For connections on B, connections will be pooled; but this will not bring you any performance since on one-server setup you did not have this part of the noise production.

How do we help this system run faster?

If these two servers are on the same machine, we should get rid of the show-off server and continue with our hardworking webserver. It adds a lot of unnecessary work to the system.

If these are separate machines, then you are being nice to web server by taking at least encyrption (for ssl) load from this poor guy. However, you can be even nicer.

If you want to continue on Apache, switch to mpm_worker from mpm_prefork. In case of 300+ concurrent requests, this will work much better. I really have no idea about the capacity of your hardware; but if handling 300 requests is difficult, I believe this little change will help your system a lot.

If you want to have an even more lightweight system, consider nginx as an alternative to Apache. It is very [easy to setup](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) to work with PHP and it will have a better performance.

Other than front-end side of things, also consider checking your database server. Connection pooling will make real difference here. Be sure if your PHP installation is configured to reuse connections to database.

In addition, if you are hosting static files on the same system, then move them out either on another web server or do even better by moving static files to a cloud system with CDN like AWS's [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)+[CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) or [Rackspace's CloudFiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/). Even without CloudFront, S3 will make you happy. Rackspace's solution comes with Akamai!

Taking out static files will make your web server "oh what happened, what is this silence? ohhh heaven!" since you mentioned this is a website and web pages have many static files for each dynamically generated html page most of the time.

I hope you can save the poor guy from the killer work.

Comment: Thanks for that very long answer on the question.

Yes, the Question was how to establish connection pooling on the (B) connection. 
As reverse Proxying is a security concept for hiding all 'working' servers behind a single reverse proxy, taking the proxy out of the game is not an option.
Removing SSL from the (B) connection between the proxy and the backend server is not an option either, as the Proxy server is the only server allowed to connect to the backend server and the only way to really ensure this is using Mutual SSL auth to authenticate the proxy against the bckend server.

Comment: The benefits I want to gain from the connection pooling on Connection (B) ist the removal of the SSL handshake overhead. The handshake is the costy thing - 300-500ms . Running a subsequent request over the already-established pooled SSL connection adds only 20ms on the backend-server's request execution time. So the goal is to remove the 300-500ms penalty on each request when not using a pooled connection.

Comment: Actually I swithed over to MPM_worker during the last days and managed to establish the connection pooling. So my initial problem is solved now. 
During my attempts to achieve the same using MPM_Prefork I encountered some problems and came across this question and started a bounty to give me some hints on how to build this using MPM_Prefork. 
As it turned out, the Apache Bug stated in the original post only applied to early Apache 2.2 versions and was not present in my Apache 2.2.22. So Connection pooling worked in both MPM_Prefork and MPM_worker for me, see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Prefork can still pool 1 connection per backend server per process.

Prefork doesn't necessarily create a new process for each frontend request, the server processes are "pooled" themselves and the behavior depends on e.g. MinSpareServers/MaxSpareServers and friends.

To maximise how often a prefork process will have a backend connection for you, avoid very high or low maxspareservers or very high minspareservers as these will result in "fresh" processes acceptin new connections.

You can log %P in your LogFormat directive to help get an idea if how often processes are being reused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped me a lot to understand whether connection pooling was even possible using MPM_prefork.
The Apache documentation ad even the mod_proxy logging in debug level is not very eloquent about whether connections are re-used or not.
In my case it turned out tht not the reverse Proxy but the backend server was the Problem. It Detected the Browser to be an MSIE by inspecting the `User-Agent` HTTP header and was thus closing the SSL connection at the end of each request. 
That's why the reverse proxy was never re-using the SSL connections to the backend server.

Comment: The 500 is yours, as your comment helped me to understand what was happening, 

I'll post an answer to point out, what was cusing the problems in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem in my case was, the the connection pooling between reverse proxy and backend server was not taking place because of the Backend Server Apache closing the SSL connection at the end of each HTTPS request.

The backend Apache Server was doing this becuse of the following Directive being present in the `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

This directive does not make sense when the backend server is connected via a reverse proxy and this can be removed from the backend server config.